# How to solve `No message found under code 'good.morning.message' for locale 'us'`?

Tags: spring, netbeans

I'm trying to test a internationalization but I keep getting the message "No message found under code 'good.morning.message' for locale 'us'." each time I make a GET request.

I'm using Netbeans IDE for my project. Below are my codes

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class RestfulWebServicesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestfulWebServicesApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
        return localeResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource bundleMessageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return messageSource;
    }
```

ControllerClass

```
@RestController
public class HelloWorldController {

    @Autowired
   private MessageSource messageSource;

    @GetMapping("/hello-world-internationalized")
    public String helloWorldInternationalized(@RequestHeader(name="Accept-Language", required=false) Locale locale) {
        return messageSource.getMessage("good.morning.message", null, locale);
        //return "Good morning";
    }
}
```

Here's my messages.properties file:

```
good.morning.message=Good Morning
```

And here's the link to my folder structure

[image: project folder structure]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Read the javadoc: it explains why your bundle can't be loaded. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html

Answer (score 0):

Change `bundleMessageSource()` name to `messageSource()`.

Comment: Hey there and welcome to SO! Your answer would benefit greatly from an explanation why this helps, so if you could [edit] that in, that would be great!